# Angularjs $scope in controller. How to get id?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-controller

Pease help me with the controller. The rails application page has selects: Group of systems and systems. Systems have equipment, systems group have systems. When I select a group of systems, I want to see the equipment of all systems belonging to this group . At the moment the equipment is shown only in the case of the selection of his system.

```
 $scope.loadEquipments = (complex_id, object) ->
  if object == 'group'
    $scope.systems = SystemResource.where
      ppr_group_system_id: complex_id
    # load equipment of system
    $scope.equipments = EquipmentResource.where
      ppr_system_id: $scope.systems

  else if object == 'system'
    # load equipment of system
    $scope.equipments = EquipmentResource.where
      ppr_system_id: complex_id
  else
    $scope.equipments      = []
    $scope.equipment_works = []
```

How to get ids of $scope.systems? Or how to do it?

Where method EquipmentFactory:

```
where: (params, successHandler) ->
  @service.query
    ppr_equipment: params
    ((equipments) -> successHandler?(equipments))
    @errorHandler
```

View:

```
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='issue_service_id'>System</label>
    <select required class='form-control' id='current_system' data-ng-model='current_system'
            data-ng-options='system.id as system.title for system in systems'
            data-ng-change="loadEquipments(current_system, 'system')">
      <option value=''>Select system</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

The same view for groups.